# Using ssh keys through ssh server with github

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

For running high performance scripts i have to use a ssh-server.

For transfering the files i have made a github repository. However when pulling from the ssh server it still asks for username and password. These it says are invalid, propably because i have 2-factor validation.

I have tried to generate a ssh key on the server, and added it to github. It however still asks for the username and password.

The reason seems to be that it looks in the openssh folder instead of the folder with the generated keygens. This folder contains files:

- ctr-cavstest
- gnome-ssh-askpass
- sftp-server
- ssh-askpass
- ssh-keysign
- ssh-pkcs11-helper

So my question is:

- Can i add any of these to github to solve the problem?
- Or is there a way to make it use the generated keys which are in a different repository?

Comment: When connecting to the GitHub repo, have you specified that your should authenticate via ssh or via credentials. Basically, what does `git remote -v` state.

Answer (score 1):

> These it says are invalid, propably because i have 2-factor validation.

That kind of warning is generally seen for HTTPS URLs, not SSH.

So check first, as commented, your `git remote -v` before doing your `git pull`.
If it starts with `https://`, try first:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```